# Handling zero cell counts in the "survey" package

Tags: r, sparse-matrix, survey, divide-by-zero

[Edited to include smaller reproducible example]

**The Goal**

I'm learning the R `survey` package to get cell proportions (specifically, row percentages) and confidence intervals for a two-way, 58 x 4 contingency table, with variance estimation taking into account the complex sample design. The 58 California counties are on the rows and a "sexual orientation" variable with four categories (straight, gay/lesbian, bisexual, and other) is on the columns.

**The Problem**

The problem is that several small counties have zero cell counts. When I try to get the table using the `svyby` method, I get the error "data length is not a sub-multiple or multiple of the number of rows."

Here's a reproducible example:

```
# Set the number of trials and the probabilities for each outcome
set.seed(16)
probs <- c(.94, .03, .02, .01)
n <- 10000

#Tables with 0s

#Create df
sogi <- data.frame(t(rmultinom(n, 1, prob = probs)))
names(sogi) <- c("straight","gay","bisexual","other")
df_sogi <- sogi %>% mutate(sexual_orientation = 
  as.factor(case_when(
    straight %in% 1 ~ 0,
    gay %in% 1 ~ 1,
    bisexual %in% 1 ~ 2,
    other %in% 1 ~ 3))) %>%
  mutate(pw = runif(n, 0.2, 3.5)) %>%
  mutate(county = as.factor(rep(LETTERS[1:10], each = n/length(LETTERS[1:10])))) %>%
  mutate(ind = row_number()) %>%
  select(ind, county, sexual_orientation, pw) 

#Check raw counts
table(df_sogi$county, df_sogi$sexual_orientation)

#Make survey design and survey design replicate objects
df_svy_z1 <- svydesign(id=~ind, data = df_sogi, weights = ~pw)

#Estimate cell means
svyby(formula = ~county, by = ~sexual_orientation, design = df_svy_z1, FUN = svymean)


#Modify table to put in zeroes
df_sogi$sexual_orientation <- ifelse(df_sogi$county %in% c("G","I") & df_sogi$sexual_orientation==3, 
       df_sogi$sexual_orientation == 0, df_sogi$sexual_orientation)

Check raw counts
table(df_sogi$county, df_sogi$sexual_orientation)

df_svy_z2 <- svydesign(id=~ind, data = df_sogi, weights = ~pw)
svyby(~factor(county), ~factor(sexual_orientation), df_svy_z2, svymean)
```

Comment: Good question. `Survey` package has been around for a while so I'm sure there is a workaround. I would trouble shoot but I'm un-able to download an RDS of that size. Perhaps make a smaller re-producible example maybe using an existing R dataset modified if necessary.

Comment: Thanks, @CCurtis. I'll work on a smaller reproducible example. Just curious: what are the criteria for meeting the minimum threshold to have my question voted up?

Comment: Anyone can upvote a question. Your question is pretty long and isn't easily reproduceable since it relys on a large dataset. A good question should be something short sweet and to the point. It should be easily reproduced with supplied code. The question should also ask a unique question that isn't easily searchable.

Comment: Read this post on asking a good question. Given you an upvote because you've obviously put a lot of work into your question before asking. https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/r-language/articles/76995406/how-to-write-a-good-r-question-with-a-reproducible-example

Comment: Thanks, @CCurtis. I'm working on a shorter reprex now but hitting snags. I'll post it when I work it out.

Comment: @CCurtis: I edited the question to include a smaller reprex. I'd be grateful if you could take a crack at it.

Comment: Looks like @Thomas Lumley beat me to it.  Glad you were able to get it resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `county` is not a factor. It's getting *converted* to a factor separately for each subset as the call is made to `svymean`, but since that call is just for a subset, the factor levels are just the levels present in the subset.

The **whole point** of factors is that they know what their possible levels are, and you lose this whole point when do the conversion this way.  You either have to convert in advance

```
df_svy_z2<-update(df_svy_z1, countyf=factor(county))
svyby(~factor(countyf), ~factor(sexual_orientation), df_svy_z2, svymean)
```

or list the possible levels explicitly in the call to `factor()`

```
svyby(~factor(county,levels=LETTERS[1:10]), ~factor(sexual_orientation), df_svy_z2, svymean)
```

This used not to be a problem very often, because the conversion to factor was done automatically when data were read in; very few people had character strings in their datasets.  Since the change to `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` as the R default, it's increasingly common for people to have variables that should be factors but that are just represented as character strings.

The problem is sufficiently common that there's a note on the help page for `svyby`

> The function works by making a lot of calls of the form FUN(formula, subset(design, by==i)), where formula is re-evaluated in each subset, so it is unwise to use data-dependent terms in formula. In particular, svyby(~factor(a), ~b, design=d, svymean), will create factor variables whose levels are only those values of a present in each subset. If a is a character variable then svyby(~a, ~b, design=d, svymean) creates factor variables implicitly and so has the same problem. Either use update.survey.design to add variables to the design object instead or specify the levels explicitly in the call to factor. The stringsAsFactors=TRUE option converts all character variables to factors, which can be slow, set it to FALSE if you have predefined factors where necessary.

As the note says, a third option is

```
svyby(~factor(county), ~factor(sexual_orientation), df_svy_z2, svymean, stringsAsFactors=TRUE)
```

but that's not best practice because it converts **all** strings to factors and because it assumes you want the set of factor levels present in the data passed to `svyby` and in their default order.

Comment: Many thanks, once again, Prof. @Thomas Lumley. Just one point on which I'm confused: when I create the data frame, I create both variables as factors:  ```mutate(county = as.factor(rep(LETTERS[1:10], each = n/length(LETTERS[1:10])))) %>%``` and ```sogi %>% mutate(sexual_orientation = as.factor(case_when(straight %in% 1 ~ 0,``` &c..  The function ```class(df_sogi$county)```, returns ```class``` for both variables. What happens that the ```survey``` suite of functions is not reading these as a factor?

Comment: Ok, my apologies.  It *is* a factor already; the problem is that you **re-convert** it into a factor in the call to svyby.  If you use `~county` instead of `~factor(county)` then everything is fine. Or if you use `~as.factor(county)`, which doesn't re-convert something that's already a factor.